# Is there a way to stop data in cell changing when I refresh/update the sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm building a table that reports the amount a client spends a day on an advertising platform using Supertmetrics. Every day I will refresh the sheet to get the new data. I have a daily budget that is calculated by dividing the number of days that are left for the campaign by the remaining budget left using this formula:

**Remaining budget/17 days**
=D54/17

I then have a separate column that calculates how much over or under the daily budget the spend is on that day by using:

**Daily budget-todays spend**
=H7-C37

As the daily budget changes every day according to how much the client spends - the data in the row from the day before changes. I need to freeze the figure on the day so that when I come back and look at the spends the next day it won't change. Is there a formula I can use to stop this data from changing?

I'm really new to using spreadsheets so I hope I've explained everything ok. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to keep a history data for each day based on the budget each day. I think you have to keep a static budget history i.e. have rows to record the budget each day and these budget numbers are static numbers with no reference to the budget column that is changing every day.

I hope the above helps.

Comment: Yes - that's correct. I ideally wanted it to do that automatically and freeze the data so I don't have to manually record it, but I'm not sure if that's possible. Thanks for your help!